# PagedList.BoundaryCallback is not triggered again

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I am trying to implement Paging with room and network call as shown in [android sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample)

onItemAtEndLoaded is called when I move to the bottom of list. In that case I insert data into room by getting result from network call.

If network call fails, and user again move to bottom of list after sometime, the boundary callback is not triggered.

Is this a bug or intended behaviour? As I do not want to implement infinite retrial. Instead only make call if user scrolls to bottom